Eclipse - run build in lxc container
I have a CMake project for cortex m7 target.
To have an easily reproductible build i provided my team with an lxc container that contains all dependencies.
The local copy of the git repository is cloned on the host and the folder is mounted on the container as well.
The only problem i'm facing is my team would like, understandably, to use eclipse to develop, build and debug on the target.
I'm already good to perform these steps within the container, using vim, make, gdb-multiarch and openocd.
For eclipse, i have no clue what to do :

should the eclipse install be on the host or on the container ? I'm already able to open graphical applications on it
if it is on the host, how can i trigger a build on the container ? same question for a debug session

My last question : is having this whole container based workflow even relevant ? My experience tells me it is great because having a reproductible build is key to have the team quickly operational, but i may be missing some points.
